# Looking for CSS columns ALA newspaper/ms-word, for content - column 1 top down, then wrapping to column 2, top down

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm automating a report we usually type manually once a month in word, and the person it is for requires that it always looks exactly how they specify - it needs to be two content columns, that wrap like MS Word / a newspaper - the end of the first column wraps to the start of the second column, the start of the second column wraps to the start of the first column on the next page.

It is a list of lists - each list is `<div><h2>List title</h2><ul> <li>...</li> </ul></div>`

Preferably, each list block would be restricted to a column, if it fits on one column

The files are created with a PHP cli script, and then opened from a local drive.  The environment is what defines our pure-CSS/HTML requirement.  Light amounts of javascript (code sizes unlikely to raise an eyebrow) are OK.  External javascript file references are not OK.  Not using javascript is preferred.

Our backup solution is to process per-report CSS code when creating the file in PHP, and we can figure that out internally if necessary.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) for this. See also

> Graceful Degradation
>
> Note that not all browsers supports these properties unprefixed. To make use of this feature in most today's browsers, each property must be written thrice: once with the -moz prefix, once with the -webkit prefix and once without prefix.

In your case this would be

```css
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
```